# Clarification on while (true) loop with embedded If-Else

Tags: c#, while-loop

I have been learning programming with C# and have come across a concept that I was not familiar with, that I am looking for clarification to help me better understand what is going on. This is not really specific to C#. It has to do with using a `while (true)` loop with an embedded `If-Else` statement.

I was working through an example in a book and found that the author used `while (true)` loops inside of a method, which was called by the `Main` method. Within the author's `while` loop was an `If-Else` that contained the return value of the method.

When I think of using `while (true)`, I think of an endless loop where you call break to get out of it. However, this loop did not need a break to get out. Rather it breaks if the condition of the `If` statement is true and loops if that condition is false. Below is an example.

How is that the while loop breaks out when there is no variable condition for it to evaluate, rather it is hard-coded "true"? Does it have something to do with being inside a method and only breaks because the method is being called by the Main? Just looking to better understand this as it is a handy technique to use for validation.

```cs
public void ValidateInteger()
{
   while(true)
   {
      if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value)
         return Console.WriteLine($"{value} is an integer")
      else
         Console.WriteLine($"{value} is not an integer, try again")
   }
}
```

Comment: The loop (and the function) ends when the `return` line is hit.

Comment: It is confusing since `Console.WriteLine` does not return a value. The author is taking a (weird) shortcut.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp that makes sense; return ends the loop. The code snippet was not an example from the book. The book example actually does return a value, not void. I just wrote something up quick that probably doesn't make sense. lol

Comment: While it's good that you try to minimize examples for use on Stack Overflow, please try to avoid writing invalid code and then asking for explanations on how it works.

Comment: There are multiple ways to break an infinite loop like this. The code can throw an exception, either explicitly with `throw new SomethingException(...);`, or as part of executing something that has a problem. You can use `return` as you have in your example, you can execute a `break;` which will break out of the loop it is placed inside.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public void ValidateInteger()
{
   while(true)
   {
      if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int value)
         return Console.WriteLine($"{value} is an integer") <-- right here
      else
         Console.WriteLine($"{value} is not an integer, try again")
    }
}
```

The return line is where the while loop breaks because there's no reason to continue the loop if a value has been returned.

Comment: That was an example, as the op said.